# How to add legend to plot with data from multiple data frames

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have scripted a ggplot compiled from two separate data frames, but as it stands there is no legend as the colours aren't included in aes. I'd prefer to keep the two datasets separate if possible, but can't figure out how to add the legend. Any thoughts?

I've tried adding the colours directly to the aes function, but then colours are just added as variables and listed in the legend instead of colouring the actual data.

Plotting this with base r, after creating the plot I would've used:

```
legend("top",c("Delta 18O","Delta 13C"),fill=c("red","blue")
```

and gotten what I needed, but I'm not sure how to replicate this in ggplot.

The following code currently plots exactly what I want, it's just missing the legend... which ideally should match what the above line would produce, except the "18" and "13" need superscripted.

Examples of an old plot using base r (with a correct legend, except lacking superscripted 13 and 18) and the current plot missing the legend can be found here:
Old: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCh1S.jpg
New, missing legend: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDTYU.jpg

**Background data**

```
head(avar.data.x)
      time          av       error
1 1.015223 0.030233604 0.003726832
2 2.030445 0.014819145 0.005270609
3 3.045668 0.010054801 0.006455241
4 4.060891 0.007477541 0.007453974
5 5.076113 0.006178282 0.008333912
6 6.091336 0.004949045 0.009129470
head(avar.data.y)
      time         av       error
1 1.015223 0.06810001 0.003726832
2 2.030445 0.03408136 0.005270609
3 3.045668 0.02313839 0.006455241
4 4.060891 0.01737148 0.007453974
5 5.076113 0.01405144 0.008333912
6 6.091336 0.01172788 0.009129470
```

**The following avarn function produces a data frame with three columns and several thousand rows (see header above). These are then graphed over time on a log/log plot.**

```
avar.data.x <- avarn(data3$"d Intl. Std:d 13C VPDB - Value",frequency)

avar.data.y <- avarn(data3$"d Intl. Std:d 18O VPDB-CO2 - Value",frequency)
```

**Create allan deviation plot**

```
ggplot()+
      geom_line(data=avar.data.y,aes(x=time,y=sqrt(av)),color="red")+
      geom_line(data=avar.data.x,aes(x=time,y=sqrt(av)),color="blue")+
      scale_x_log10()+
      scale_y_log10()+
      labs(x=expression(paste("Averaging Time ",tau," (seconds)")),y="Allan Deviation (per mil)")
```

**The above plot is only missing a legend to show the name of the two plotted datasets and their respective colours. I would like the legend in the top centre of the graph.**

How to superscript legend titles?:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=avar.data.y,aes(x=time,y=sqrt(av), 
color =expression(paste("Delta ",18^,"O"))))+
  geom_line(data=avar.data.xmod,aes(x=time,y=sqrt(av), 
color=expression(paste("Delta ",13^,"C"))))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red"),name=NULL) +
  scale_x_log10()+
  scale_y_log10()+
  labs(
    x=expression(paste("Averaging Time ",tau," (seconds)")),
    y="Allan Deviation (per mil)") + 
  theme(legend.position = c(0.5, 0.9))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `color` inside the `aes` and add a `scale_color_` function to your plot should do the trick.

```r
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=avar.data.y,aes(x=time,y=sqrt(av), color = "a"))+
  geom_line(data=avar.data.x,aes(x=time,y=sqrt(av), color="b"))+
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("red", "blue"),
    labels = expression(avar.data.x^2, "b")
  ) +
  scale_x_log10()+
  scale_y_log10()+
  labs(
    x=expression(paste("Averaging^2 Time ",tau," (seconds)")),
    y="Allan Deviation (per mil)") + 
  theme(legend.position = c(0.5, 0.9))
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Made a couple of formatting changes to fit my needs. Any idea how to superscript part of the legend labels? I tried to use the expression(paste( route but that left an error: 
"Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object?" Added that code at the end of my post.

Comment: That gets me an "Error: Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): colour = expression(paste("Delta 18"^"O")). 
Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add stat()?" when I use this:

   `geom_line(data=avar.data.y,aes(x=time,y=sqrt(av), 
    color=expression(paste("Delta 18"^"O"))))+ 
    geom_line(data=avar.data.xmod,aes(x=time,y=sqrt(av), 
    color=expression(paste("Delta 13"^"C"))))+`

Comment: you would need to write it without the paste. I change my answer above

Answer (score 5):

You can make better use of ggplot's aesthetics by combining both data sets into one. This is particularly easy when your data frames have the same structure. Here, you could then for example use `color`.

This way you only need one call to `geom_line` and it is easier to control the legend(s). You could even make some fancy function to automate your labels. etc.

Also note that white spaces in column names are not great (you're making your own life very difficult) and that you may want to think about automating your `avarn` calls, e.g. with `lapply`, which would result in a list of data frames and makes the binding of the data frames even easier.

```r
avar.data.x <- readr::read_table("0 time          av       error
1 1.015223 0.030233604 0.003726832
2 2.030445 0.014819145 0.005270609
3 3.045668 0.010054801 0.006455241
4 4.060891 0.007477541 0.007453974
5 5.076113 0.006178282 0.008333912
6 6.091336 0.004949045 0.009129470") 
avar.data.y <- readr::read_table("0 time         av       error
1 1.015223 0.06810001 0.003726832
2 2.030445 0.03408136 0.005270609
3 3.045668 0.02313839 0.006455241
4 4.060891 0.01737148 0.007453974
5 5.076113 0.01405144 0.008333912
6 6.091336 0.01172788 0.009129470")

library(tidyverse)

combine_df <- bind_rows(list(a = avar.data.x, b = avar.data.y), .id = 'ID')

ggplot(combine_df)+
  geom_line(aes(x = time, y = sqrt(av), color = ID))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue"),
    labels = c(expression("Delta 18"^"O"), expression("Delta 13"^"C")))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: OK for two lines but what if you have 100 lines and just want have a different colour for say just one of them?

Comment: @Markm0705 assign a new variable grouping your 99 lines in one group and the one line in the other and color by this new variable