Having problem adding legend onto my ggplot when ggplot's data argument is NULL
New to r here, so please bear with me. I am sure this is something simple to solve. I have this plot here and want to add a legend to distinguish which line represents the "Tailwater Gauge" and which one represents "Site L5".

Here is the code I am using to make this graph.
 ggplot(DailyDownGaugeAvg, aes(Date, DailyGaugeHeightAvg)) +
  geom_line(
    data = DailyDownGaugeAvg,
    color = "blue")

  ggplot(NULL, aes(Date, mean_temp)) +
    geom_smooth(data = DailyAvgL5, alpha = 0.3) +
    geom_line(data = DailyAvgL5, color = "blue") +
    
    geom_smooth(data = DailyDownGaugeAvg, color = "red", alpha = 0.3) +
    geom_line(data = DailyDownGaugeAvg, color = "red") +
    
    xlab('Date') + ylab('Daily Average Temperature (Celcius)') +
    ggtitle("Daily Average Temperature
Site L5 vs Tailwater Gauge")

I am having trouble finding an answer online as most solutions are just adding a color() argument to the ggplot argument, but it does not seem to work for me because the data = NULLL in the ggplot argument and I can not find a way to make a legend that applies to what I have. Any help much appreciated. Thanks.
dput(head(DailyAvgL5))
structure(list(Date = structure(c(19791, 19792, 19793, 19794, 
19795, 19796), class = "Date"), mean_temp = c(9.98765502929687, 
9.884833984375, 8.01781209309896, 8.70198394775391, 9.21991678873698, 
9.69807739257812), ciInf = c(8.5062704241455, 8.40344937922362, 
6.53642748794758, 7.22059934260253, 7.7385321835856, 8.21669278742675
), ciSup = c(11.4690396344483, 11.3662185895264, 9.49919669825033, 
10.1833685529053, 10.7013013938884, 11.1794619977295)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

dput(head(DailyDownGaugeAvg))
structure(list(Date = structure(c(19789, 19790, 19791, 19792, 
19793, 19794), class = "Date"), mean_temp = c(7.94, 8.465625, 
7.965625, 7.64673913043478, 8.63645833333333, 9.146875), DailyGaugeHeightAvg = c(15.5787368421053, 
12.3515625, 9.34770833333333, 12.2685869565217, 15.6577083333333, 
16.4609375), ciInf = c(6.75421576137529, 7.27984076137529, 6.77984076137529, 
6.46095489181007, 7.45067409470863, 7.96109076137529), ciSup = c(9.12578423862471, 
9.65140923862471, 9.15140923862471, 8.83252336905949, 9.82224257195804, 
10.3326592386247)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

SOLUTION
I was able to get it to work with the following code.
 ggplot(DailyDownGaugeAvg, aes(Date, DailyGaugeHeightAvg)) +
  geom_line(
    data = DailyDownGaugeAvg,
    color = "blue")

  ggplot(L5DownDailyMerge, aes(Date, NULL, color())) +
    geom_smooth(aes(x = Date, y = DailyAvgL5Temp), alpha = 0.25) +
    geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = DailyAvgL5Temp, color = "L5")) +
    
    geom_smooth(aes(x = Date, y = DailyAvgDownstreamGaugeTemp, colour = "Tailwater Gauge"), alpha = 0.25) +
    geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = DailyAvgDownstreamGaugeTemp, colour = "Tailwater Gauge")) +
    
    scale_colour_manual("",
                       values = c("L5"="blue", "Tailwater Gauge"="red")) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
    xlab('Date') + ylab('Daily Average Temperature (Celcius)') +
    ggtitle("Daily Average Temperature
Site L5 vs Tailwater Gauge")


The best thing to do is to combine your data into one data.frame with a variable that indicates which series each value is from. Otherwise if you want a legend you need to specify color inside the aes(). The duplicate describes both methods.

You might also find it helpful to read about tidy data.  Your datasets aren't tidy [because you have one piece information recorded in two columns (DailyAvgL5 and DailyGaugeHeightAvg - I think) and another piece of information (location: Tailwater Gauge or Site L5) not recorded at all], and that is the root cause of your problem.

Thanks. Still trying to figure out how to merge the two dataframes together. Not finding a simple solution. In regards to @Limey, Daily Avg L5 stores the daily avg of temperatures at site 5 and DailyGaugeHeightAvg stores the height of the gauge at the tailwater site. They are two diferent sites and not the same data. I will add a location though, that sounds like a good idea.

They are the same information in the sense that they are both "the value I want to plot".  Adding a location will allow you to write, say, geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = ValueIWantToPlot, colour = Location) and your legend will appear - though you may well then need to customise it.

Ok I will go ahead and add a location to both dataframes and see if I can get that to work. Thanks. Appreciate you taking the time to help.

Are you saying to merge the two dataframes together and then use a location column in order to dinstinguish between the two?

Try this duplicate instead, it's perhaps a bit closer to your actual problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58789168/how-to-add-legend-to-plot-with-data-from-multiple-data-frames:
